# How to select one element from a class with multiple elements

Tags: html, css

I have a project that i'm working on for a couple days and now i just can't move on with this in my sight, i need help

I tried several selectors but none of them could solve this if someone can help i would apreciate a lot

```
.container_about {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```
 <main>
    <section class="container_about">
      <div class="item">
        <h3>
          bla bla bla
        </h3>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam quas eligendi mollitia iusto quam pariatur
          aliquid provident voluptatem dolor eius excepturi, tempore ipsum corrupti! Esse, dolorem. Nam unde ad optio.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <img src="imagens_edits/undraw_engineering_team_a7n2.svg" alt="teste de imagem">
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
```